# Access php object key in Woocommerce product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an object inside `$args['product']` containing this key

```
["prices_array":"WC_Product_Variable":private]
```

When I `var_dump($args['product'])`, that key and its values are shown but when I loop, that key is skipped

```
foreach ($args['product'] as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($key);
    var_dump($value);
}
```

How can I access this key in php? I even tried to `json_encode($args['product'])` but same result, that key is skipped.

Thanks

Comment: Because that is private property and you can't access from outside

Comment: Thanks @MASIDDIQUI, I was starting to realize it. So there is no way?

Comment: You can use object getter methods to retrieve certain properties... ex `$product->get_price()` retrieves the `price` property. This will be extra important in WooCommerce 2.7 as directly accessing properties will throw PHP errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property you're trying to retrieve is private. It's not designed to be accessible by your code. Instead you need to use a method.

Use `get_variation_prices()`.

```
$prices = $product->get_variation_prices();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php